# Is Bayesian updating commutative?

Tags: bayesian

Is Bayesian updating always commutative?
For example, suppose two scientists share a prior.
Each performs an experiment. Then they share the results with each other.
Each Scientist saw her results first, and only then the result of her peer.
Are we assured that their posterior view is the same?

Is this easy to prove?

Comment: The updating is multiplicative which is  a commutative operation

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand what do you mean by multiplicative, can you elaborate?

Comment: you may benefit from reading about *exchangibility*.

Comment: A related albeit vastly more complex topic is [Aumann's agreement theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1868055).